# Checking a child's entries for a match

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('players').child(playerId).child('voters');
ref.child(uid).once('value', snap => {
    var key = snap.key;
    console.log("snapkey: " + key + " uid: " + uid)
    if (key === uid) {
        console.log("Exists")
    } else {
        console.log("Doesn't exist")
    }
});
```

I'm trying to see if a variable `uid`, which holds the users unique ID from firebase-auth is present in my database's `voters`

[image]

So for me, when I'm using the app, my uid is vKl6rIUuI0WsbeWVORz3twPUfnd2. So if I go to vote on this Firstname Lastname person, it should tell me I exist in the above image's scenario.

The problem is, it seems to always say it exists. The console.log for key and uid are both putting out my uid. Is it something with the `ref.child(uid)...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('/players/' + playerID + '/voters');

ref.once('value', snap => {
    var value = snap.val()
    console.log(value)
    if (value !== null) {
        console.log("Exists")
    } else {
        console.log("Doesn't exist")
    }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Answer (score 1):

A snapshot will *always* have a key.  Always.  And it will be at the location you requested by reference.  Whether or not there is *data* behind that key is irrelevant to the fact that the snapshot will always have a key.

What you need to do is check the data behind that key.  Is it null?  Then there's no data there.  A number?  That's data, and it's present.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.exists()` method:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('players').child(playerId).child('voters');
ref.child(uid).once('value', (snap) => {
    console.log(snap.exists());    // This will print true or false
});
```